# Relevance of "Dhol Ganwar Shudra Pashu Nari, Sakal Taadana Ke Adhikari"

Tags: belief, caste-system, women, ramcharitmanas

> प्रभु भल कीन्ह मोहि सिख दीन्हीं।
>   मरजादा पुनि तुम्हरी कीन्हीं॥
>   **ढोल गवाँर शूद्र पशु नारी।
>
>   सकल ताड़ना के अधिकारी॥**
>
> Drums, the illiterate, **lower caste**, animals and **women** deserve a beating to straighten up and get the acts together.

This is written in Ramcharitmanas by Tulsidas. Similar [post from Quora](http://www.quora.com/Dhol-Ganwar-Shudra-Pashu-Nari-Sakal-Taadana-Ke-Adhikari-What-does-Tulsidas-precisely-mean-by-this-quote) discusses, how this was said by Sea deity to Lord Rama before creating Ramsetu.

Without criticizing anyone, I would like to know how is this quote relevant in today's time and what could have lead an intellectual like Tulsidas to write such a verse?

[Note: From a source, I also heard that Chaanakya had approved this quote.]

Comment: Goswami Tulsidas did not know then, that one day he would become "World Famous" and that a simple quote of his, with respect to a small event, in a big narrative like Ramayana, would get pinpointed.He was a very simple/straightforward ,but, superlative devotee of Sri Rama.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is one of the most misinterpreted verses of Ramcharitmanas. Tulsidas had no intention of showing women low by citing this verse.

We have to see the context of the verse:
This verse isn't told by Ram or Tulsidas himself. This was told by "sea god" in fearful state begging his life. He can tell anything in life saving condition. Furthermore here he is shown as a villain. Ram tells him **idiot**. Kakbhusundi tells him **नीच**  . So there is no importance of citing this verse. One can't condemn the writer of a film by citing the verse of antagonist, this case is similar.

This happens in Sundara kanda of Ramcharitmanas as following:

> विनय न मानत जलधि जड़ गए तीनि दिन बीती।
>    बोले राम सकोप तब भय बिनु होई न प्रीति ।।
>   
>   Three days had elapsed, the **crass** ocean would not answer the Lords prayer. Råma thereupon indignantly said
>   "There can be no love without
>   inspiring fear."
>   
>   
>   लछिमन बान सरासन आनू । 
>   सोषों बारिधि बिसिख कृसानू।।
>    **सठ सन बिनय कुटिल सन प्रीती** । 
>   **सहज कृपन सन सुंदर नीती**।। 
>   ममता रत सन ग्यान कहानी। 
>   अति लोभी सन बिरति बखानी।। 
>   **क्रोधिहि सम कामिहि हरि कथा** । 
>   ऊसर बीज बएं फल जथा।। २
>    अस कहि रघुपति चाप चढावा । 
>   यह मत लछिमन के मन भावा।।
>    संधानेउ प्रभु बिसिख कराला । 
>   उठी उदधि उर अंतर ज्वाला।। 
>   मकर उरग झष गन अकुलाने । 
>   जात जंतु जलनिधि जब जाने ।।
>    कनक आर भरि मनि गन नाना । 
>   **बिप्र रूप धरी आयउ तजि माना**।। ४ 
>   
>   Lakshmana, bring Me My bow and arrows; I may as well dry up the ocean with a missile presided over by the god of  fire. **Supplication before an idiot** , friendship with a rogue, inculcating liberality  on a born miser, talking wisdom to one steeped
>    in worldliness, glorifying dispassion before a man of excessive greed, a lecture on
>    mindcontrol to an irascible man and a discourse on the exploits of Hari to a libidinous person are **as futile as sowing seeds in a barren land.** So saying, the 
>   Lord of theRaghus strung His bow and this stand (of the Lord) delighted Lakshmans 
>   heart. When the Lord fitted the terrible arrow to His bow, a blazing fire broke out in the 
>   heart of the ocean; the alligators, serpents and fishes felt distressed. When the god presiding over the ocean found the creatures burning, he gave up his pride and,
>   assuming the form of a Brahmana, came with a gold plate filled with all kinds.
>   
>   काटेहिं पइ कदरी फरइ कोटि जतन कोउ सींच।
>   बिनय न मान खगेस सुनु डाटेहिं पइ  **नव नीच** ।। ५८ ।। 
>   
>   Though one may take infinite pains in watering a plantain it will not bear fruit unless it is hewed. Similarly, mark me, O king of birds, (continues Kakbhusundi) a **vile fellow** heeds no prayer but yields only when reprimanded.
>   
>   
>   सभय सिंधु गहि पद प्रभु केरे । 
>   छमहु नाश सब अवगुन मेरे।। 
>   गगन समीर अनल जल धरनी । 
>   इन्ह कइ नाथ सहज जड़ करनी।।
>   तब प्रेरित मायाॅ उपजाए। 
>   सृष्टि हेतु सब ग्रंथनि गाए।। 
>   प्रभु आयसु जेहि कहं अस कहई । 
>   सो तेहि भाॅति रहें सुख लहई।। २ ।। 
>   प्रभु भल कीन्ह मोहि सिख दीन्ही।
>    मरजादा पुनि तुम्हरी कीन्ही।।
>    **ढोल गवांर सूद्र पसु नारी ।
>
>    सकल ताड़ना के अधिकारी।। ३ ।।**
>    प्रभु प्रताप मैं जाब सुखाई ।
>    उर्तारेहि कटकु न मोरि बडाई।।
>    प्रभु अग्या अपेल श्रुति गाईं । 
>   करौं सो बेगि जो तुम्हहि सोहाई।। ४।। 
>   
>   The god presiding over the ocean clasped the Lordís feet in dismay. Forgive, my lord, all my faults. Ether, air, fire, water and earth all these, my lord, are inert by nature. It 
>   is Måyå (Cosmic Nature) which brought them forth for the purpose of creation under an inspiration from You; so declare all the scriptures. One would attain happiness in life only by remaining where he has been placed by the Lord. My Lord has done well in giving me a lesson; but You have fixed certain innate treat for everyone. **A drum, a rustic, a sudra, a beast and a woman all these deserve instructions.** ll be dried up 
>   and the army will cross over; but this will bring no credit to me. Your command, however is inviolable; thus declare the Vedas, I shall do at once what pleases You.

Further the verse can be taken as positively also :

ढोल गवाॅर =  ignorant who is like dhol (without intellect)

  सूद्र पशु नारी = women with low animal character

Similarly there are other dialogues too spoken by others. In Chaupai of 4th Doha of Aryanya kanda Anusuya tells Sita

> धीरज धरम मित्र अरु नारी  ।
>    आपद काल परखिये चारी ।।
>   
>     Patience, Religion, Friend and Women are tested in difficult times.

Here 'women' are compared with 'religion', 'friend', i.e. with good qualities.

Hence these are all due to the context or person who is telling.

Answer (score 1):

We need to
We need to understand poetry, rather than translate the verse in Ramcharitramanas by Tulsidas in prose form.

Samudra also says in 1st line प्रभु भल कीन्ह मोहि सिख दीन्हीं।मरजादा पुनि तुम्हरी कीन्हीं॥" "Prabhu you gave me Shiksha (Dhand/punishment), while everything is your creation".
Samudra also says in 2nd line "ढोल गवाँर शूद्र पशु नारी। सकल ताड़ना के अधिकारी॥ "Drum, Rustic, Shudra, Woman all deserve that punishment"

Shows that Tulsidas has written that 'Drum, Rustic, Shudra, Animal, Woman" need Shiksha from Prabhu Sri Ram, where Dhand (punishment) is used as poetic allegory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).