# Feminist's claim that the Vedas, Ramayana and Mahabharata were written by male writers

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, ramayana, women, bhishma

How do you go about refuting a [feminist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feminism)'s (male or female) claim that the Vedas, epics like Ramayana and Mahabharata were authored by male persons, so no wonder some of the principles, ideologies and ways of life prescribed are pro-male/[male-chauvinistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chauvinism#Male_chauvinism) and are meant to suppress women?

The speaker in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/v/pOuEGSFp0Iw?start=159&end=278&autoplay=1) jokingly points out that Sita could have very well asked Rama to accompany her into the fire to prove *together* that their sanctity is intact.

In [Anushasana Parva of Mahabharatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anushasana_Parva#Duties_and_rights_of_women), Bhishma says:

> The goddess (Lakshmi) asserts she does not reside in a woman who is sinful, unclean, **always disagreeing with her husband**, has no patience or fortitude, is lazy, quarrelsome with her neighbors and relatives.

...implying the husband is usually right.

**In defense:**

Regarding the Vedas, it can be argued that they are [*Apauruṣeyā*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apauru%E1%B9%A3ey%C4%81) (authorless or written by gods) hence were written neither by male nor female person.

Comment: Yeah, you're right that at least the Vedas are Apaurusheya, so they weren't authored by men.  Among the sages who heard the Vedas during Tapasya there were some Brahmavadini women.  By the way, the Mahabharata quote reminds me of the Mahabharata quote in this question: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7356/36

Comment: The issue is that there are really so many suppressive males exist in society that even though you defend genuinely, the feminists would count you among those chauvinists. There is a sloka in Gita too which supposedly lowers women (along with Vaishya, Shudra). If someone asks for knowing purpose then only it should be answered not for debates. @KeshavSrinivasan, here is another one: [Relevance of "Dhol Ganwar Shudra Pashu, **Nari**, Sakal Taadana Ke Adhikari"](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8242/1049)

Comment: @iammilind I can understand women being put in the same category as fourth-caste people (neither of them have any Dharmas relating to Yagnas), but what Gita verse puts Vaishyas also in the same category?  Vaishyas are Dvijas and wear the sacred thread.

Comment: You may be interested in this excerpt from the book "Purva Mimamsa in its Sources",  summarizing what the Mimamsa Sutras say about the role of women in Yagnas: http://gdurl.com/HlCl

Comment: The vedas were not 'authored' by man. The vedas are the eternal truths revealed by God.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda if I stand in shoes of a feminist, then I can easily refute it by saying, "Ok, I agree that Vedas were recited by God. But they were derived into books for you and me to read by some men and see they have made it male centric!" In today's time just "who said it?" is not enough but "why said it?" is also required.

Comment: @iammilind What specifically in the vedas are male centric?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda By the way, you're a follower of Vivekananda, right?  Vivekananda didn't believe the words of the Vedas were eternal, only that the ideas represent eternal truths: "The meaning of the statement is not, as is erroneously supposed by some, that the words of the Vedas are anadi, but that the spiritual laws inculcated by the Vedas are such."  Is that your view as well?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan where did Krishna say women are 4th category?

Comment: @AnilKumar Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that woman are of the fourth caste.  I meant women are in the same category as fourth-caste people in the sense that neither of them are allowed to conduct Yagnas.  See the gdurl link in my comment above for more detail on the topic of women and Yagna Dharma.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Why sorry? i am not offended but just wanted to know where Krishna said it.

Comment: @AnilKumar I just mean sorry for the misunderstanding.  In any case, here is the Gita verse that iammilind was referring to: http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/32

Comment: What's the problem about just agreeing, that they were authored by males and represent a male-centered worldview that might have to be corrected in some parts? For this would be the just thing to do...

Comment: @zwiebel Maybe you can expand on that and post an answer.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, AnilKumar, BTW that BG 9.32 is translated in slightly politically correct way. The real translation (in Gitapress, Gorakhpur) is bit stronger: `"O PArtha, those who take shelter only under me, be it of sinful origin [like] women(Stri), business-class(Vaishya), worker-class(Shudra) also; even they go to supreme position"` So as it's seen, "Lower" and "Sinful" have a slight difference. "Sin" is generated when a Jiva attaches self with an action, however "Lower" birth is a fruit of such sinful life. Here keyword is "shelter", but often critics look at *Stri/Vaishya/Shudra* :-).

Comment: I don't really understand the purpose of your question or what answer you are expecting. What reason should there be to refute such a claim? Does Hinduism even has a need to refute this claim? It looks like you are only trying to spread your opinion through the words "meant to suppress women?" which is biased from the actual meaning of Hindu scriptures.

Comment: @GabeHiemstra Please read my question again and also the answers. The intent of my Q is to bring out the best answers which can refute the claims of few narrow-minded thinkers who think Hinduism is oppressive towards women. Whoever answered my question clearly understood what is that I'm looking for and I've even accepted one of the answers. "Does Hinduism even has a need to refute this claim?" -- IMHO, such kind of thinking is detrimental to this site. We need to even allow  Q's that question the fundamentals of Hinduism. We should not frown upon and scare away users with such rhetoric.

Comment: The speaker supports Duryodhana's belief in his wife and friend. So one can have belief on their wife and friend, and can abuse other's wives. The speaker didn't know it? How does he support it?

Comment: Bhishma during the time of the Mahabharata was the embodiment of society and social values and views at the time his downfall was being so stuck to them that he forgot dharma from what I know. While he is a righteous and pious person his views may differ from that of other characters the Mahabharata gives views from characters each with their own values and points.

Comment: Men sacrificed their lives for women in war, men provided for women and somehow male philosophers are sexist for writing epics.

Comment: Also wdym suppress women? Men and women have naturally different roles in society.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## tl;dr

It's true that the scriptures indeed prescribe principles, ideologies and ways of life which are pro-male. But it's based on physical & mental attributes associated with male-female body & mind.
In other context, during *Anushasana Parva*, [Bhishma also described women](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b010.htm) in highest regard:

> <sub>Respect, kind treatment, and everything else that is agreeable, should all be given unto the maiden whose hand is taken in marriage. Her sire and brothers and father-in-law and husband's brothers should show her every respect and adorn her with ornaments, if they be desirous of reaping benefits, for such conduct on their part always leads to considerable happiness and advantage. If the wife does not like her husband or fails to gladden him, from such dislike and absence of joy, the husband can never have issue for increasing his race. **Women, O king, should always be worshipped and treated with affection. There where women are treated with respect, the very deities are said to be filled with joy.** There where women are not worshipped, all acts become fruitless. If the women of a family, in consequence of the treatment they receive, grieve and shed tears, that family soon becomes extinct. Those houses that are cursed by women meet with destruction and ruin as if scorched by some Atharvan rite. Such houses lose their splendour.</sub>

According to Vedic scriptures, it's believed by saints that Women cannot be happy on their own. This should be the reason, why Bhisma discussed certain rules, which are apparently seems little hard in today's time.

> <sub>There is the well-known declaration of the scriptures that **women are incompetent to enjoy freedom** at any period of their life. *If this were not the path trodden by the righteous, how could this scriptural declaration exist?* ... In childhood, the sire protects her. The husband protects her in youth. When she becomes old, her sons, protect her. **At no period of her life does woman deserve to be free.**</sub>

---

Since you are asking about "how to defend/refute"; Your answer depends on the "predominant" quality (*Guna*) of the audience.

## Answer to *Tamasic* (*Mithyachari*, Ignorant, Argumentative)

They might have come across male chauvinism & women suppression somewhere (media, magazine, TV, movies, friends) and just based on their gut feeling, be it right or wrong, they will make some non-sense arguments with you. If you too argue with patience for a while, you can see their voice raising, anger, frustration, making faces, jokes, making fun in front/behind you. Answer to such people (don't lie but just avoid them):

*"hmmm .. even Krishna also says in Gita that women are of lower birth. Isn't it strange?"*<sup>[1]</sup>

Nevertheless, if you are successful in convincing them sweetly, then those may become your followers!

## Answer to *Rajasic* (*Dambhi*, Passionate, Debater)

Such people consider, "winning a habit" or "success a journey". They are not foolish or senseless but often well versed with their convenient knowledge. They may not open their horizon if not treated in certain way and would find ways to prove their point to win over you for their pride.

Though they hardly surrender, if they are helplessly proven wrong, then they might end up hurting you or even create a propaganda. Since they are intelligent (not enlightened), it's your duty not to misguide them just to serve their ego, yet be very brief. Answer to such people:

*"Rama, Krishna, Bhishma said such pro-male ideologies in a time when there were no female foeticides, no wife beatings, no restrictions from social interactions, no honor killings, no dowry harassments. Hence their view was neutral and eternal. If you feel that either they or their teachings were non-sense, then better to leave the discussion here.*
*If ideology of unequal rights to male/female is wrong according to some people's opinions, then it's a stalemate or deadlock of their trust."*

Depending on their readiness, you may also disclose some of the details from below, but be careful. You may end up inviting more trouble while fixing one. First you have to explain *Varna Vyavastha*<sup>[2]</sup>, but then the anti-caste people will be hurt. When you explain the real definitions of 4 *Varnas*, then the so called higher castes (just due to surnames) would be hurt. All these troubles also don't guarantee that your male-female differentiation would be accepted. :-)

## Answer to *Sattvik* (*Sthitapragya*, Calm, Knowledge seeker)

> Stree(woman) = Shakti(power)

Women forms are integral part of Vedic culture. They are prayed in form of *Shakti*, which is evident as their association with many deities.   *Shakti*/*Stree* has right to choose their responsible *Swami* (*Swayam-Vara*). **Swa-dharma of *Shakti*/*Stree* is to get molded & acts in accordance of its *Swami*(master). That's why a wife is called *Ardhaangini* (half body of husband).** She acts as of her husband commands to his own self.

Due to moldable nature, due importance is given of securing women. Arjuna feared that post Mahabharata, if women of all warriors get polluted (i.e. marrying to anyone due to lack of men), then the whole society will be vanished.<sup>[3]</sup>

Wise man doesn't give controls to the *Rajo Guna*, which usually prevails in women.
Like "power", women naturally have a nature of attachment. Various attachments are associated with *Rajas*. It supposedly increases during [MC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_cycle), hence it's called *Rajaswala*. Draupadi was dragged by Dushasana during her this period and she remained so attached to the destruction of the Kauravas, that before Krishna's final peace negotiation, she asked "What will happen to her insult, should the Kauravas agree for peace?!"
Hence, among 3 *Gunas*, *Rajas* is the one which must be consciously controlled<sup>[4]</sup>.

Some may ask, why women are compared with *Shudra*s (as of it's insulting). We should remember that a soul/*jiva* holding certain body is independent of gender & division. According to *Karma*, it has acquired certain type of material nature constituting certain division and gender. Similar traits of moldable nature and surrendership are defined for *Shudra*s too.
*Shudra*s are not so called lower castes, but they are just "trainees" in any given fields<sup>[5]</sup>. In today's hybrid time, we associate the divisions with surnames or body characteristics, i.e. *Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaisya, Shudra*; or even *Stree, Purusha*. Which is not correct. It should be done with respect to *tendency/Swabhaav* and *duty/Dharma*; i.e. *Swa-Dharma*.

In a society, *Brahmin*s will be least<sup>[6]</sup> in numbers, little more will be *Kshatriya*s<sup>[7]</sup>, many more will be *Vaisya*s and most will be *Shudra*s. Especially in today's time, all those who do job and earn money for well being can be considered *Shudra*s (ignore their surnames). A *Shudra* trained under *Brahmin/Kshatriya/Vaisya* becomes *Brahmin/Kshatriya/Vaisya* after perseverance (call it *Yajna*). This 4 *Varna*s are eternal and are not limited to India but all human societies<sup>[8]</sup> Similarly a woman married to the man of X division becomes X herself.

After reading above, if we refer to what Bhishma says in *Anushasana Parva*, it's easily understandable that mother goddess who is *Shakti* will not reside in those women who are not acting according to Lakshmi's (*Stree*) own Swa-Dharma which is surrendering to Swami. It's so trivial!

## Answer to *Atman* (*Brahman*, inner self, soul)

<sup>[9]</sup>

<sub>**References**  (taken from vedabase.com; need better translation)</sub>

> <sub>[1] [BG 9.32](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/32) — O son of Pṛthā,
>   those who take shelter in Me, though they be of lower birth – women,
>   vaiśyas [merchants] and śūdras [workers] – can attain the supreme
>   destination.</sub>
>
> <sub>[2] [BG 4.13](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/4/13) — According to
>   the three modes of material nature and the work associated with them,
>   the four divisions of human society are created by Me. And although I
>   am the creator of this system, you should know that I am yet the
>   nondoer, being unchangeable.</sub>
>
> <sub>[3] [BG 1.40, 1.41, 1.42](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/1) — When
>   irreligion is prominent in the family, O Kṛṣṇa, the women of the
>   family become polluted, and from the degradation of womanhood, O
>   descendant of Vṛṣṇi, comes unwanted progeny. — An increase of unwanted
>   population certainly causes hellish life both for the family and for
>   those who destroy the family tradition. The ancestors of such corrupt
>   families fall down, because the performances for offering them food
>   and water are entirely stopped. — By the evil deeds of those who
>   destroy the family tradition and thus give rise to unwanted children,
>   all kinds of community projects and family welfare activities are
>   devastated.</sub>
>
> <sub>[4] [BG 3.37](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/3/37) — The Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead said: It is lust only, Arjuna, which is born of
>   contact with the material mode of passion and later transformed into
>   wrath, and which is the all-devouring sinful enemy of this world.</sub>
>
> <sub>[5] [BG 18.44](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/44) — Farming,
>   cow protection and business are the natural work for the vaiśyas, and
>   for the śūdras there are labor and service to others.</sub>
>
> <sub>[6] [BG 18.42](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/42) —
>   Peacefulness, self-control, austerity, purity, tolerance, honesty,
>   knowledge, wisdom and religiousness – these are the natural qualities
>   by which the brāhmaṇas work.</sub>
>
> <sub>[7] [BG 18.43](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/43) — Heroism,
>   power, determination, resourcefulness, courage in battle, generosity
>   and leadership are the natural qualities of work for the
>   kṣatriyas.</sub>
>
> <sub>[8] [BG 18.41](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/431) — Brāhmaṇas,
>   kṣatriyas, vaiśyas and śūdras are distinguished by the qualities born
>   of their own natures in accordance with the material modes, O
>   chastiser of the enemy.</sub>
>
> <sub>[9] [Ramana
>   Maharshi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramana_Maharshi#Silence):
>   *Silence is the true & perfect upadesa.*</sub>

Comment: Well crafted answer though I don't agree with some of the points. Well done.

Comment: Gita verse 4.13 doesn't say anything against the notion that Varna is birth-based.  People are born into a particular family based on their gunas. Your statement "Anyone takes birth at any womb, hence we cannot point someone as Brahmin, Kshatriya, Vaisya, Shudra" is wrong.  The womb you're born into depends on your actions done in past births.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I don't deny either the birth or the family of soul. Go above few lines, "it's foolish to judge a *varna* based on today's surname based casts". Because lot of hybridization has happened in effect of inter marriages that that one cannot decide a person's division based on division of its womb. I came across Osho's commentary on *Varna-sankara praja* that in earlier times it was easy for a soul to decide a womb due to stronger divisions. Later it appeared more difficult to choose a womb due to hybridization. In nutshell, one can't claim that I am Brahmin because of family.

Comment: @iammilind Well, if your family has had a lot of caste mixing in the past, then that may be an issue.  But there are lots of families, especially in South India, who have taken great pains to maintain caste purity.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan :) Don't take it personally. It's not about my, your or someone's family tree. What are you referring is genetic purity. That has been maintained for quite sometime all across India and probably continuing. But that purity again relies on surname based divisions which is nonsense. e.g. A girl and a boy are marrying. Both are so called higher casts. Girl's father is an MD in Govt. unit. Boy is an architect in MNC. Their early family lineages also constitute such respectable jobs/posts. Then it's not Brahmin-Brahmin but Shudra-Shudra marriage with utmost purity of cast lineage.

Comment: @iammilind I quite agree with you that it's extremely problematic when some people stop following their Varna dharmas - it's one of the signs that it's the Kaliyuga. But the son of two evil Brahmanas is still a Brahmana - that's well-established in Hindu scriptures.  Now it's a different story if a Brahmana is so bad that he's never even initiated into the sacred thread - in that situation there are severely bad consequences for the offspring, because the child can only be initiated if his father has already been initiated. But a Brahmin living like another caste still has Brahmin offspring.

Comment: Our swadharna is based on our caste at birth (and our birth is determined according to our gunas).  If you are born to Brahmana parents, then you are a Brahmana and your swadharna is the dharma for Brahmanas.  You shouldn't do the dharma of someone else just because you feel inclined to do it.

Comment: I have to really wonder about this answer. Any feminist known to me would jump into your face, feeling that your answer, though meant as a refutation is steeped in chauvinism. To go into detail just a bit: "moldable nature" or "women naturally have a nature of attachment" are just claims of yours (and a lot of others, for that matter) without any real evidence to support them. And here any feminist would tell you, that these claims of yours are gender-politics with a very obvious background...

Comment: @zwiebel, don't be confused with "woman" and "female". Even if they have same meaning, in this answer's context they are treated differently. Here "man" means head who makes decision(it can be male or female) & woman is the one who follows (again male or female). Like how "BrAhman" is a division (among 4) & not a caste, In same way "woman" is a type of *Purusha* (consumer) & not a gender. In old society man-->male & woman-->female were easier, but today it can't be. Feminist issues are related to female, which they generalize for woman. Hope this clears the stand.

Comment: @iammilind I do find this an exceptionally weird terminology. Normally we are talking about sex, which is biological and makes men men and women women. Secondly we are talking about gender, which is supposedly purely social and where we talk about female gender and male gender. Not the other way round...

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Even though, scriptures doesn't refute birth based *varna* determination, there are examples of *mahanubhavas* who even after being born in different *varnas* altered them by their *purushartha*. Valmiki, Dwaipayana Vyasa, Parashurama etc.

Comment: @VineetMenon, VyAsa was always a *Brahman*. According to *AnushAsana Parva*, Brahman can marry B+K+V, Kshatriya can marry K+V & Vaishya can marry only V. But they can have carnal enjoyment with a Shudra woman without entering into marriage. Satyavati was a Shudra (fisherman's daughter) & VyAsa's father, rishi ParAshara was a Brahman. BTW, IMO the birth based Varna system were valid only up till the *Varna* system was followed religiously. Since Mahabharata, there were so many wars & due to excessive killings, there was a hybridisation. Hence, today's castes seldom represent correct *Varna*.

Comment: @iammilind, IMO you are mixing dharmasashtra with shruti. If the union of Parashara with Saryavati wasn't a proper marriage, how can his child with Satyavati be legal heir of Brahmana varna? Although, I agree that today's *jati* (I refuse to use the word caste as it's not an Indian word) doesn't represent *varna*.

Comment: @iammilind  this is one of the best answers that I've read on this site. (y)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I can answer that question it is true the womb you are born into is based on karma. But, it is not simply due to the fact you attain that womb that you are of that varna. It is distinguished by your actions and qualities in this life. Also, I forgot which Upanishad, but it states one is born into the womb of a Brahmin if they do good karma. Not that they are Brahmin. Look at this section in Mahabharta https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7458.html Here we can see the same message being put forth by Yudishtir. (I spelt his name wrong sorry)

Comment: @zwiebel what's weird is you separate gender from sex, since gender is a social view based on bias in sex also this is based on the author's observations of women or rather Bhishma's observations which were recorded by the author, they may not be scientifically true, that's not the point these are his experiences based events which happened in his life.

Answer (score 11):

First, I have to say I am a feminist myself. I am also one who has great reverence for Hindu heritage and scriptures and ascended masters (rishis). Claims and opinions of any texture are a result of one's understanding of the subject matter. There was a time in India , primarily after Macaulay, when our scriptural knowledge and understanding of rishi hridayam got diluted, distorted , relegated to attics and even discarded. The feminism movement was born at a time when women across the world, including India needed a sociological , political, philosophical and economic voice. Since the movement itself did not explore the rishi hridayam of India, only superficial interpretations of the scriptures became prevalent which only led to their denouncement. Historically as well as scripturally, the Vedic period speaks of women enjoying equal if not superior rights. For e.g., history says widows remarried freely during the Vedic period.

As for refuting the kind of claims you mention, If one were to read the scriptures as well as dharma sastras, one would understand that both men and women, as well as all the castes have  designated dharmas which were all designed to uphold the functioning of humankind. For dharma is what shall "hold up the sky".

To take the specific example you quote, it is not to be interpreted that the woman should be submissive. But rather that she should avoid certain behaviors in order to keep the family-machine well-lubricated. It is not dissimilar to advice dispensed by psychologists, management coaches or even agony aunts to those looking to cohabitate or work collaboratively for any length of time within a system.

Similar dharmas and instructions can be found for men as well. For e.g., the man only has the right to earn but must give his earnings to the lady of the house and only she has the authority to spend it judiciously. The husband must not take decisions without consulting his wife and taking her consent. Men are forbidden from ever appropriating monies that belong to the woman. It is stree dhana and must not be touched. So on and so forth.

Also, there are numerous examples of strong women in our scriptures who not only enjoyed equal rights but asserted their authority also when the time came. Sita berated Rama for refusing to let her accompany him to the forests. Draupadi berated Yudhishtara for triggering their servitude and destitution. Tara and Mandodari strongly advised their respective husbands about the right path. It is another point that the said husbands paid no heed. It must be noted that the wives were not punished for having an opinion or having the temerity to assert those opinions.

Another counter-argument to the problem you pose is the Worship of Mother Goddess. It  has been popular from time immemorial and one of its basic tenets is that all women other than your wife must be revered as one's mother.

Having said that, feminism still has relevance in this world. However, Indian scriptures are not anti-women. We just need to read them properly and understand the dharmas and dharma sukshmas presented in them. Ultimately, each jeeva has a dharma that must be upheld in order to hold up the sky. This is the underlying principle of all Hindu scripture.

Comment: NIce answer. And, to add to that, women at a certain period of time even have more liberty in going out with other men than her husband as I discuss in my answer [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8731/1018). Apart from that there were many major Yagnas where participation of women was considered necessary like Ashwamedha Yagna, etc. Lord Rama even had to sit with the idol of Devi Sita in her absence. Also, we heard of 'SwayamVAR' many times, have we heard of SwayamVADHU. This clearly shows that man have to compete and have to be potent enough to win the lady.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: Good answer. There are many examples in the scriptures as well as examples in Indian history.

Comment: Can you please cite the shlokha or translation to support: _Draupadi berated Yudhishtara_? I recently listened to a discourse on Mahabharata where the speaker (on the contrary) said, Draupadi did not find any fault in Yudhishtara after his loss at the game of dice. Much later on, during their exile, she does question him and laments what did they finally achieve by sticking to Dharma. (If you are interested, [here's the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3adHIx18vx4&feature=youtu.be&t=10680) to YouTube video (language spoken is Telugu)

Comment: @sv. I recall at least one scene from virata parva. Will get you the sloka references soon. Remember, just because the emotions are couched in gentle words does not mean it is not a scolding.

Answer (score 5):

One can argue against the feminist stand and claim that the scriptures have an anti-men bias by picking up isolated passages.

> **On women**
>
> Women can commit no fault. It is man who becomes stained with fault.
> Indeed, in consequence of the natural weakness of the sex as displayed
> in every act, and their liability to solicitation, women cannot be
> regarded as offenders.

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCLXVI

**Men regarded as embodiments of hell**

> Pingala said, ‘…What women is there that regards that Supreme Soul as
> her dear Lord, even when he comes near? I am now awake. I have been
> roused from the sleep of ignorance. I am no longer influenced by
> desire. Human lovers, who are really the embodied forms of hell, shall
> no longer deceive me by approaching me lustfully. Evil produces good
> through the destiny or the acts of a former life. Roused (from the
> sleep of ignorance), I have cast off all desires for worldly objects.
> I have acquired a complete mastery over my senses. One freed from
> desire and hope sleeps in felicity. Freedom from every hope and desire
> is felicity. Having driven off desire and hope, Pingala sleeps in
> felicity.'

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CLXXIV

You will find this passage here: https://archive.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b001.htm

One should judge a scripture by what it says in essence and not by picking up stray passages.

Comment: 2ND PART IS 100% LIES!! Mahabharata S.P. CLXXV is given here and there is no such thing mentioned !! https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b002.htm . **1ST PART is  is opinion of 2nd-varna person with little knowledge NOT A HOLY MAN. It is against all other HOLY scripture**

Comment: @R.Kaushik I cannot verify what he said in both cases they're either opinions or more likely glorifications or praises versus actual teaching.