# What is the correct translation of rig veda book 8 hymn 33 verse 17

Tags: translation-request

> 17 Indra himself hath said, The mind of woman brooks not discipline,
> Her intellect hath little weight.

This is the translation by Ralph t Griffith.
And it is also in the wiki.

**What is the correct translation of rig veda book 8 hymn 33 verse 17**(Please give multiple translations) .

Comment: you need to give sanskrit equivalent verse because sankrit sameword have minimum 3 eytomological meaning Indra. one who controls sense or lord of sense. Indra is lakshmi.. Indira is Lord krishna himself because he is  lord of lord himself and indra mean vayu because he too can control the sense by life breath, if you attended yoga session they would given instruction to watch your breath on each pose, so lord lifebreath is vayu that is indra because one can control with help of lifebreath

Comment: @PrasannaR OK but 8 have given the verse number and chapter  you can find it.

Comment: @PrasannaR I can not find the sanskrit equivalent.

Comment: @Prasanna R  I can not find the sanskrit equivalent

Comment: Stree word in sanskrit means one who have wrong notion of the Lord I.e. I can become Lord himself and I'm lord and mr lord is outside and upper not inside myself  or my personal lord has no connection with diety I worship I'm just body now if apply the meaning you will get correct meaning

Comment: Its beautiful meaning i have got.. "Lord krishna says The mind of those who have wrong notion of the lord brooks no discipline, those intellects hath little weight.". (my pranams to Bannaje Govindacharya) for deciphering the meaning of stree..

Comment: Add some detail about what issue you find from the existing translation and some relevant context so that one can explain those point in answers according.

Comment: Ralph T. Griffiths was an early Western orientalist and translator who did not have a good understanding of Hinduism or of Sanskrit. Too many see his translation on the internet as it is 'free'.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda that's the exact reason I asked this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> इन्द्रश्चिद्घा तदब्रवीत्स्त्रिया अशास्यं मनः । उतो अह क्रतुं **रघुम्**॥१७॥

Griffith translated *raghum* as less weighted. In Sanskrit dictionary, this word has various meanings.

[image]

Raghum also means *quick*. Let's check other translations.

## Acharya Shri Rama Sharma

> The statement of Lord Indra was also here that it is very difficult to take control of the mind of women; **Because their resolve is unstoppable.**

[image]

## Jayadeva Sharma

[image]

## Pt. Harisharan Siddhantalankar.

[image]

## H.H.Wilson

[image]

Wilson's translation is not different from Griffith but in commentry he gave the clarification about the verse that Indra is not talking about all the women. This hymn 8.33 is all about Asanga who became a female due to curse. **The mind of a Woman here only refers to this Asanga who became a female.** So, Indra is saying Asanga’s mind is not discipline and her intellect is very small, here it refers to only that Asanga who became a woman, not all women.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer